# Cannot Install GPE on Fresh Eclipse Kepler

Tags: java, eclipse, google-plugin-eclipse

I got a fresh download of Kepler and installed it in my Ubuntu13 running Oracle JDK7, but I cannot install the Google Plugin for Eclipse for GWT and App engine development because installing it from its update site only display tools for Android and NDKs. See screenshot here: http://pasteboard.co/1mX0ivtk.png

Please how do I handle this ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you uncheck the "Hide items that are already installed" checkbox and see it if list the Google Plugin for Eclipse.